# Frameless window shows dark border on linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtplugin

I created a dialog with shadow effect

```
 Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::Dialog| Qt::FramelessWindowHint;

 QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
 effect->setOffset(4);
 effect->setBlurRadius(9);
 contWdget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

This works perfect on windows but when I open the same dialog in Linux its showing dark black color border around the dialog.

What work around I need to do to make it work on Linux.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share a snapshot of the problem (Windows vs Linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To frameless window in linux use `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` like this :

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog();
dialog->setWindowFlags( Qt::FramelessWindowHint );
dialog->show();
```

[image: screenshot]

**Tested on :**

`Qt Creator 4.3.1`

`Based on Qt 5.9.0 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)`

`Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`